# Call to .NET Rest Web Service throws Bad Request

Tags: .net, rest

I'm having a problem calling a REST Web Service provided by a .NET application of mine, related to character encoding.

I'm sending something like this:

http://:/DotNetApplication/RestService.svc/**eyJudW1iZXIiOiI5NDU5NjA5M%2BDAiLCJtc2ciOiJQYXJhIGNvbmZpcm1hciBhIHJlY**

The query string is **this one**, it's URL encoded and because of the %2B (+) character I'm getting a ***Bad Request - Invalid URL*** error.

If this character isn't specified the Web Service responds successfully.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What about if you url encode the % character?

Comment: What do you mean? If I encode the % character I'll get something like %252B right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wan't the %2B character but rather the format that data was being parsed.

**Incorrect:**
http://:/DotNetApplication/RestService.svc/eyJudW1iZXIiOiI5NDU5NjA5M%2BDAiLCJtc2ciOiJQYXJhIGNvbmZpcm1hciBhIHJlY

**Correct (query string)**
http://:/DotNetApplication/RestService.svc/?request=eyJudW1iZXIiOiI5NDU5NjA5M%2BDAiLCJtc2ciOiJQYXJhIGNvbmZpcm1hciBhIHJlY

Since data was being passed to the REST Web Service through a path structure instead of a standard query string, the limit of characters was 254.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try to encode the `%` char, event it produces itself a `%`.

According the [RFC 2396, page 9](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396):

```
Because the percent "%" character always has the reserved purpose of
being the escape indicator, it must be escaped as "%25" in order to
be used as data within a URI.  Implementers should be careful not to
escape or unescape the same string more than once, since unescaping
an already unescaped string might lead to misinterpreting a percent
data character as another escaped character, or vice versa in the
case of escaping an already escaped string.
```

Comment: Changed it to http://:/DotNetApplication/RestService.svc/eyJudW1iZXIiOiI5NDU5NjA5M%252BDAiLCJtc2ciOiJQYXJhIGNvbmZpcm1hciBhIHJlY and the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be not the %2b problem but rather the character size. I'm using get but the URL is about 350 characters long.